# Is there a Google SDK for rendering Google Maps in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-maps-android-api-2

Is there a Google SDK for rendering Google Maps in Unity ?
Or will there be one in the near future ?

It seems like there's only solutions for native-mobile and web right now.

Thanks, 
Ash

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/gaming/

Comment: Thanks @xomena,
I've looked at the info at that URL, but there doesn't seem to be an SDK listed for Unity in the documentation. Only SDKs for native Android, iOS, and an SDK for web/JS applications. 

If there's an SDK for Unity I've missed, can you provide a direct link to documentation for it ?

Comment: The Unity SDK is not free, so you cannot see public available documentation. You should reach out to Sales team in order to get more information.

Comment: Got it - thanks @xomena.

Comment: Does it mention this somewhere I missed ?
Or would it make sense for Google to mention it, even tho it's not publicly available ?